# Getting perl output concurrently from Java

Tags: java, swing, perl, swingworker

I am writing a Swing application that will execute long running perl scripts. I need to display the interim output of an execution concurrently even as the process executes in the background. Using the following piece of code returns the output at process completetion.

```
BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                // read the output from the command
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
```

How can I get the ouput concurrently? I am using Swingworker to display the returned information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is autoflushing enabled on the Perl side? If not, then you'll be buffering.

Set `$|` to a non-zero value through `$|++;` or `$| = 1;` to enable autoflushing.

See [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for more details.

Comment: I would definitely recommend `$| = 1;` over `$|++`, as someone may have turned it on by using `$|--`. ( I have seen both `$|++` and `$|--` used here on StackOverflow, so this isn't an idle thought. ) At any-rate `$|` is a flag, and should be treated as such.